# Unable to build nodejs app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

So I'm trying out this [go-react](https://bitbucket.org/kthakoreNewtopia/react-go/src/87c411501e71?at=master) example but I am not able to build it by following the instructions. Running the following command:

```
~/react-go/jsapp$ npm run build
```

I get the following error:

```
> example-js-app@0.0.0 build /home/x/react-go/jsapp
> browserify -t reactify -r react -r ./src/App > ../webapp/static/bundle.js

/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
npm ERR! weird error 127
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Here's the `package.json` content:

```
{
    "name": "example-js-app",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
       "build": "browserify -t reactify -r react -r ./src/App > ../webapp/static/bundle.js",
       "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
   },
   "dependencies": {
     "envify": "^3.4.0",
     "react": "^0.14.0",
     "browserify": "^11.2.0",
     "reactify": "^1.1.1"
   }
}
```

I'm new to nodejs. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you read `/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian`?

Comment: What is your node version?

Comment: @Moogs I was using the old version. Now I upgraded it to 4.2.1 and I get a lot of errors now than before. Here's the error: http://pastebin.com/VSqQ1dfn